# Is there a way to trade without going online?

Tags: warframe

So I recently sold my PS4 with my Warframe account with Rhino Prime on it. I know it can't be migrated onto PC so that's a loss I'm willing to take but is there a way to trade on the website so my PS4 Warframe can give my PC Warframe Rhino Prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there is no web-based interface for trading at the moment (as of 01/01/17).

Additionally, it should be noted that you can't trade fully-assembled frames - so you wouldn't be able to transfer your Rhino Prime, anyway.